# maven profile in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

I'm new in IntelliJ IDEA.
I don't understand this flag.
Where I show all profiles? How are they used?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This project defines a Maven profile in the `pom.xml` named `aws` and IntelliJ shows it this way. My guess would be that it contains the configuration for deploying to Amazon Web Services.

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html